# Facebook open graph get 'me' works but 'me?fields=name' returns oAuth error

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

After reading the long title, Here is my current status:

1. I have managed to login to Facebook (Authorize method returns complete).
2. I have implemented an **Async Task** to get '**me**' data - everything works fine.
3. I tried to change the call to **me?fields=name**, **gender** and I get an error like -
   `"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."`

I tried to Google it and read about it but because people implement their code in million languages I didn't manage to find a good solution for my problem.

Please advise!
Oz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this issue I changed the way I address the facebook objec:
Instead of sending it **me?fields=name, gender**

I changed to this code:

```
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("fields", "name, gender, picture");
        String jsonString = params[0].request("me", bundle);
```